# Insert to a sorted slice

Tags: go

What's the most efficient way of inserting an element to a sorted slice?

I tried a couple of things but all ended up using at least 2 appends which as I understand makes a new copy of the slice

Comment: Insertion into `slice` (or `Dynamic Array`) is `O(n)`. You might want to look into `Binary Search Tree` where insertion time on average is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it requires 2 appends to add a single element to a slice. You could do it in a single line with nested appends, but there's no need for that. Extend the slice, shift the elements, insert the new element.

Answer (score 18):

Here is how to insert into a sorted slice of strings:

Go Playground Link to full example: https://play.golang.org/p/4RkVgEpKsWq

```
func Insert(ss []string, s string) []string {
    i := sort.SearchStrings(ss, s)
    ss = append(ss, "")
    copy(ss[i+1:], ss[i:])
    ss[i] = s
    return ss
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Seems to be the method the golang sort package is expecting, given their Search functions.

Comment: This is a perfect answer for strings.  I have made it generic (Go 1.18) so it will work with a slice of any ordered type. See answer below.

Comment: anyone, please explain this function, I cant understand this.

Answer (score 11):

I like @likebike's answer but it only works for strings.  Here is the generic version that will work for a slice of any ordered type (requires Go 1.21):

```
func Insert[T cmp.Ordered](ts []T, t T) []T {
    i, _ := slices.BinarySearch(ts, t) // find slot
    return slices.Insert(ts, i, t)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/JE3h_AuDzA-

For Go 1.18 to 1.20 you need the slices and constraints packages at `golang.org/x/exp`

```
func Insert[T constraints.Ordered](ts []T, t T) []T {
    i, _ := slices.BinarySearch(ts, t) // find slot

    // Make room for new value and add it
    ts = append(ts, *new(T))
    copy(ts[i+1:], ts[i:])
    ts[i] = t
    return ts
}
```

Comment: I want to like this, but there are at least two problems with it. The first is trivial, it doesn't handle the initially empty slice case, but that's easy to cover. The second is more troubling - BinarySearch requires that its slice argument be sorted, but appending the dummy zero value does not enforce that requirement. Is that guaranteed not to matter in this case?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the dummy is only there to extend the underlying array; the actual dummy value is overwritten. BinarySearch() shouldn't care; however its a requirement for it to return an accurate index.  Regardless, you could always move the dummy append after the call to BinarySearch() to maintain consistency.
There is also the issue if the index returned by BinarySearch is the last element of the slice (array); will cause an out of bounds error (pretty trivial)

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug - the call to `append` should have been after `BinarySearch`.  I have fixed this and also updated for Go 1.21.
@cyrix: yes `dummy` was just to get a value of type T but apparently the idiomatic way to do this in`*new(T)`.

Answer (score 10):

If the slice has enough capacity then there's no need for a new copy.
The elements after the insert position can be shifted to the right.
Only when the slice doesn't have enough capacity,
a new slice and copying all values will be necessary.

Keep in mind that slices are not designed for fast insertion.
So there won't be a miracle solution here using slices.
You could create a custom data structure to make this more efficient,
but obviously there will be other trade-offs.

One point that can be optimized in the process is finding the insertion point quickly. If the slice is sorted, then you can use binary search to perform this in `O(log n)` time.
However, this might not matter much,
considering the expensive operation of copying the end of the slice,
or reallocating when necessary.

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to the problem: finding where to insert the value and inserting the value.

Use the [sort package](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) search functions to efficiently find the insertion index using binary search.

Use a single call to `append` to efficiently insert a value into a slice:

```
// insertAt inserts v into s at index i and returns the new slice.
func insertAt(data []int, i int, v int) []int {
    if i == len(data) {
        // Insert at end is the easy case.
        return append(data, v)
    }

    // Make space for the inserted element by shifting
    // values at the insertion index up one index. The call
    // to append does not allocate memory when cap(data) is
    // greater ​than len(data).
    data = append(data[:i+1], data[i:]...)

    // Insert the new element.
    data[i] = v

    // Return the updated slice.
    return data
}
```

Here's the code for inserting a value a sorted slice:

```
func insertSorted(data []int, v int) []int {
    i := sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= v })
    return insertAt(data, i, v)
}
```

The code in this answer uses a slice of `int`.  Adjust the type to match your actual data.

The call to sort.Search in this answer can be replaced with a call to the helper function [sort.SearchInts](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#SearchInts).  I show sort.Search in this answer because the function applies to a slice of any type.

If you do not want to add duplicate values, check the value at the search index before inserting:

```
func insertSortedNoDups(data []int, v int) []int {
    i := sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= v })
    if i < len(data) && data[i] == v {
        return data
    }
    return insertAt(data, i, v)
}
```

Comment: data = append(data[:i+1], data[i:]...) how is this internally doing? Is this allocating memory for data[i:]? If not, because these indexes are overlapping, after first item data[i] is copied to data[i+1], how can data[i+1] copied to data[i+2]?

Comment: @MengZhao The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) *The built-in functions append and copy assist in common slice operations. For both functions, the result is independent of whether the memory referenced by the arguments overlaps.*.   One way to handle this overlap is to copy from the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a heap:

```
package main

import (
   "container/heap"
   "sort"
)

type slice struct { sort.IntSlice }
func (s slice) Pop() interface{} { return 0 }

func (s *slice) Push(x interface{}) {
   (*s).IntSlice = append((*s).IntSlice, x.(int))
}

func main() {
   s := &slice{
      sort.IntSlice{11, 10, 14, 13},
   }
   heap.Init(s)
   heap.Push(s, 12)
   println(s.IntSlice[0] == 10)
}
```

Note that a heap is not strictly sorted, but the "minimum element" is guaranteed
to be the first element. Also I did not implement the `Pop` function in my
example, you would want to do that.

https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches mentioned here to insert into the slice when the position `i` is known:

```golang
data = append(data, "")
copy(data[i+1:], data[i:])
data[i] = s
```

and

```golang
data = append(data[:i+1], data[i:]...)
data[i] = s
```

I just benchmarked both with `go1.18beta2`, and the first solution is approximately 10% faster.

Answer (score 2):

no dependency, generic data type with duplicated options. (go 1.18)

time complexity : Log2(n) + 1

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/constraints"
import "golang.org/x/exp/slices"

func InsertionSort[T constraints.Ordered](array []T, value T, canDupicate bool) []T {
    pos, isFound := slices.BinarySearch(array, value)
    if canDupicate || !isFound {
       array = slices.Insert(array, pos, value)
    }
    return array
}
```

full version : https://go.dev/play/p/P2_ou2Fqs37

Comment: thanks for @Andrew , replace my binary search algo with bundled package.

Answer (score 1):

Extending upon @andrew-w-phillips's answer, here is a slightly more generic version that does not require `constraints.Ordered` of `T`, but instead accepts a comparison lambda (and makes use of Go 1.21's new sort [standard libary additions](https://pkg.go.dev/gonih.org/cmp)):

```golang
// Returns slice ts with element t inserted in-order according to comparison function less
// Requires ts already be sorted
func Insert[T any](ts []T, t T, less func(T, T) bool) []T {
    var dummy T
    ts = append(ts, dummy)

    i := sort.Search(len(ts)-1, func(i int) bool {
        return less(ts[i], t)
    })

    copy(ts[i+1:], ts[i:])
    ts[i] = t
    return ts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

play : https://play.golang.org/p/dUGmPurouxA

```golang
array1 := []int{1, 3, 4, 5}

    //want to insert at index 1
    insertAtIndex := 1
    temp := append([]int{}, array1[insertAtIndex:]...)
    array1 = append(array1[0:insertAtIndex], 2)
    array1 = append(array1, temp...)

    fmt.Println(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. It basically uses the golang sort package

```
package main

import "sort"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    data := []int{20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32}
    var items = []int{23, 27}
    for _, x := range items {
        i := sort.Search(len(data), func(i int) bool { return data[i] >= x })
        if i < len(data) && data[i] == x {
            fmt.Println(i)
        } else {
            data = append(data, 0)
            copy(data[i+1:], data[i:])
            data[i] = x
        }
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```